# Sharing folders over VPN, Windows 7 does not ask for username and password

Tags: windows-7, vpn, permissions, shared-folders

So I have to Windows 7 machines and am trying to share folders between them.
Default permissions are:

```
SYSTEM
John
Admins
```

If I leave it like that, the remote machine will simply be denied access. "Windows can't access..."
If I give permission to EVERYONE then it will access just fine.

What I would like is for the remote computer to be prompted for username and password of the John account.

Password protected sharing has been tested both enabled and disabled. I've looked around and wasn't able. It simply denies access unless I add permissions to EVERYONE or NETWORK at which point it will simply grant access without any security.

Thanks in advance and sorry if I might be overlooking something simple.

edit, If i add credentials of the remote machine onto the credentials manager it will work. It will grant me access, however this is not the solution I was looking for, I'd would still like it to prompt for credentials.

Comment: Can you please confirm whether these machines are all on a Windows Domain or are they all stand-alone?

Comment: You need to ensure you are granting permission to the user account that's being used for the VPN authentication to get into the network.  If the VPN user will have to provide specific credentials (for user John) when trying to connect to the shared folder (by using `Run As` for example).  Also ensure that you are setting correct permissions on both the share itself, as well as the files/folders being shared.

Comment: What @techie007 said, by default Windows will just try to access the directory using current credentials and if it is unable to do so it will not prompt for alternative credentials.

Comment: Have you tried granting access to the `Authenticated Users` group?

Comment: @SaUce Windows will prompt for alternate creds in certain situations.

Comment: @techie007 how can I do that though? I can't seem to add a user from a diferent computer. trying to give permission to \\remotePC\remoteUser and windows doesn't let me.

Comment: @SaUce tried that, doesn't work just get denied access.